# Where exactly to place "...[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL..."?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to make a table cell that when tapped calls a phone number and I think the code I must use is;

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:thenumber"]];

But what happens is that the call gets placed automatically, as soon as the app is opened and therefore I think the problem is the location of the code.
Where does it need to be placed in order to achieve the desired cell functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thank You but how does this "know" which cell is the "...openURL..." meant for?

Comment: Assuming you're wanting all cells in the tableview to call some number, create an array of NSString or NSURL with a number for each row, then use [indexPath row] inside the method to choose the right one

Comment: Like Rich Tolley says you should use the indexPath.row to determine which cell was clicked. If you subclass the cell you can store data (NSString * phoneNumber in your case) in it and call it by accessing the cell in an array when created.

Answer (score 1):

It should be placed in the 
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
method in the tableview's delegate.

Answer (score -2):

Thank You all for Your kind answers that are correct but (with Your help) I have found a simpler solution;

```
- (void)didTap_tableViewCell2:(UIView *)cell {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:thenumber"]]; }
```

Comment: is this a tableview delegate? I've never used this. You really should look into the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate. Because from this, I assume you are creating a method for each tablecell? Which is pretty bad design. If you need help using a table view we can help you.

Comment: This looks like a good one for what you're trying to do: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/

Comment: But really if you just add `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { NSLog(@"Selected Row %d", indexPath.row;}` I think you will understand how it works